# any idea on how to display user-input html in your web page when you are using some 3rd party css framework

Tags: html, css, web

I have a problem that on my website, i allow users uploading html (may be with some style) and my webpage is under some css framework which means it is hard for me to do a css reset. so what is the best way to show these user-input html on my page? i am think put these html into a standalone page and show it in iframe but want to see if there is any better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the html in a special div with id "user-input", and do a css reset on that div only. But then of course the user-input css also need '#user-input' in their css rules, or this html should use inline styling.

Comment: you know, it is very hard to manually reset every css, like color, margin, etc. any idea on how to do it easily? wondering if there is an existing css file that could reset all the css to browser-default

Answer (score 0):

Iframe is definitely the way to do it: in the end you want to emulate what the html will look like in a customer's browser, so the best way you can ensure this kind of isolation is in a frame/separate window. Another benefit you have is that you even can host these uploaded htmls from a different domain, and then you don't have to worry about a user trying to create some rogue html that accesses stuff on your domain that they shouldn't be accessing...